# Jest mock multiple services in one test file Nest Js

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, nestjs

I'm trying to mock two services in one jest test file. The first one is perfectly mocked, but the second one isn't.

> TypeError: this.orderService.payAllWithIds is not a function

spec file:

```
// overview.controller.spec.ts

import { OrderService } from './orders/order.service';
import { TableService } from './tables/table.service';

jest.mock('./tables/table.service');
jest.mock('./orders/order.service');

describe('OverviewController', () => {
  let controller: OverviewController;
  let orderService: OrderService;
  let tableService: TableService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [OverviewController],
      providers: [
        OrderService,
        { provide: getModelToken('order'), useValue: OrderSchema },
        TableService,
        { provide: getModelToken('table'), useValue: TableSchema },
      ],
    }).compile();

    controller = module.get<OverviewController>(OverviewController);
    orderService = module.get<OrderService>(OrderService);
    tableService = module.get<TableService>(TableService);
  });

describe('payTable', () => {
    describe('when payTable is called', () => {
      beforeEach(async () => {
        await controller.payTable(tableStub()._id);
      });

      it('then the service is called', () => {
        expect(tableService.removePaymentRequest).toBeCalledWith(tableStub()._id);
        expect(orderService.payAllWithIds).toBeCalled();
      });
```

The mock:

```
// __mocks__/order.service.ts

import { tableWithOpenOrder } from 'test/stubs';

export const OrderService = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
  payAllWithIds: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue([tableWithOpenOrder()]),
});
```

**UPDATE**

I found out that when I `console.log(orderservice)`, the mock of the table service is logged... How can I prevent this?

Comment: add some `console.log` in `__mocks__/order.service.ts` to see if this file is evaluated

Comment: When I add a console.log('test') in the `__mocks__/order.service.ts` it logs in the console. So the file is used in the test...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the `OrderService` you have there isn't a valid provider. You should use something like `{ provide: OrderService, useValue: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(...) }`

Comment: btw see this lib https://www.npmjs.com/package/@golevelup/ts-jest

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well, what worked for me (although not intuitive at first glance) is the mock file needs to be within the **Module folder of what you are mocking**, for example, using your code above your directory may look like this:

```
app
 --Table
    --Table.service.ts
 --Order
    --Order.service.ts
 --Overview
    --Overview.controller.ts

Adding the mocks below

app
 --Table
    --Table.service.ts
 --Order
    --Order.service.ts
 --Overview
    --__mocks__
        --Order.service.ts
        --Table.service.ts
    --Overview.controller.ts

I needed to add the mock folders to their respective directories for it to work, like the following:

app
 --Table
    --__mocks__
        --Table.service.ts
    --Table.service.ts
 --Order
    --__mocks__
        --Order.service.ts
    --Order.service.ts
 --Overview
    --Overview.controller.ts
```